# Bloquear registros o mostrar mensajes despues de un tiempo JQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenos dias quisiera obtener guias, ideas, ejemplos o alguna manera de lograr lo siguiente:

Tengo **registros** en mi **base de datos** que hago hora por hora, el **objetivo** de esto es lograr que si despues de **15minutos** del ultimo registro me muestre un div con un mensaje donde me muestre que ya supere los 15minutos y no he hecho un **registro** o simplemente **bloquear** mi boton para hacer el registro y tener que dar el acceso yo mediante un **pin**(esto creo que ya seria algo mas complicado pero es la idea mas adelante).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla la genero con php y en cada registro tengo un datetime para saber la hora de su registro, espero darme a entender y si ocupan algun dato me lo hagan saber.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código más o menos que ya tienes hecho para lograrlo?

Comment: Realmente nada solo ideas, penseba hacerlo con una variable en PHP pero pues seria estatica y  no estaria tomando la hora del servidor en tiempo real, entonces po reso no opte por eso, pensaba asi y despues que excediera el tiempo bloquear el boton con un if.

Comment: @EduardoMX cuando realices la ultima inserción ejecuta un **interval** que bloquee el boton en la cantidad de milisegundos equivalentes a 15 minutos, luego si haces una nueva inserción  antes de ese tiempo despeja el intervalo con **clearInterval**  saludos